# PHP: My first Login System wont verify Password

Tags: php, sql, authentication

Iv'e tried my first login system, and hang up at the verification of the password.

The query to check if the user exists works, but the check for the right password doesnt.

PHP:

```
<?php
  $user = $_POST['namex'];
  $host = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "";
  $dbname = "mydb";
  $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
  $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = :s");
  $stmt->bindParam(':s', $user);
  $stmt->execute();
  $count = $stmt->rowCount();
  if($count == 1)
  {
    $stmt2 = $db->prepare("SELECT password FROM accounts WHERE username =:s");
    $stmt2->bindParam(':s', $user);
    $stmt2->bindParam(':pw', $upw);       //here set the password from the database
    $inputpass = $_POST["pwx"];         //here set the input password
    if(password_verify($inputpass, $upw)){          //here try to check for the right input
      session_start();
      $_SESSION["namex"] = $user;            //here will start session for the input user
      echo "Youre logged in";
      //header("Location:loggedin.php");
    }
    else {
      echo "Password incorrect!";
    }
  }
  else{
    echo "This Account doesnt exists!";
  }
?>
```

HTML:

```
<form action="../login.php" method="post">
  <div>
    <input class="Namebox" id="namex" name="namex" required placeholder="Benutzername">
    <label for="namex" class="labelname"></label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="password" class="pwbox" id="pwx" name="pwx" required placeholder="Passwort">
    <label for="pwx" class="labelpw"></label>
  </div>
  <button class="login" type="submit" value="submit">Anmelden</button>
</form>
```

Hope somebody can help me.

Regards Kevin

Comment: First of all, you do not need to connect twice to the database.

Comment: okay thanks, i removed the second connection.

Comment: You prepare `$stmt2`, then bind to `:pw` which isn't in the statement, but you also don't execute it.

Comment: I understand the problem. So, how get i the password in the result that i can bind it to  
`$upw`?

Comment: Also, bindParam is for putting a variable _into_ the query, not getting a value out from the results.

Comment: And actually you don't even need that second SELECT - you've already fetched all the same data from the first one!

Comment: Just [fetch](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) the first row from the first query's results and get the password value from that and put it into $upw

Comment: Like this: `$stmt->bindParam(':pw', $upw);` ?

Comment: No. Read all my comments again.

Comment: Okay i tried with `$upw = $stmt->fetchColumn(1);` but my `var_dump($upw);` returns: bool(false) Password incorrect!

Comment: Maybe the password isn't in column 1? I don't know the order of your columns. easier to fetch the row (as I gave you documentation for earlier) as an associative array and then get the column value out by name instead of number. e.g. `$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); $upw = $row["password];`

Comment: Okay, after this i got this error: `Undefined array key "password" in C:\Program Files\XAMPP\htdocs\metinserver\login.php on line 24
NULL Password incorrect!` 

Thats in my db: 
id, username, password, email
`17 | kiki | Heres the pw hash | 1234@1234.de` 

and with `var_dump($row);` i got this output: `array(0) { } NULL Password incorrect!`

Comment: Not sure why you got a different result with my suggestions and the answer below, since they're identical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the second sql query, you can verify the password by editing the code as follows

```
  # ...

  $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
  $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = :s");
  $stmt->bindParam(':s', $user);
  $stmt->execute();
  $count = $stmt->rowCount();
  if($count == 1)
  {
    $user = $stmt->fetch();
    $inputpass = $_POST["pwx"];        
    if(password_verify($inputpass, $user["password"])){         
      session_start();

  # ...
```

Comment: `$upw = $user['password'];
if(password_verify($inputpass, $upw)){ ` 

This function! Thanks Bro